# Pasar un tipo de array a otro TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ocupo setear un array con otros datos de un array, tengo un par de clases en typescript con el que hago estos arrays, mmm pero veo que un campo es de tipo numero y el otro es string, entonces no puedo seteralo, hay manera de setearlo o se tiene que cambiar el tipo y dejarlo igual para las 2 clases

```
export class ListA
{
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

export class ListB
    {
       id: string;
       name: string;
    }
```

**Ejemplo pasar array B al A:**

```
let userListB: ListB[] = 
[
 { 
  id: "1",
  name: "John";
 },
 { 
  id: "2",
  name: "Mike";
 }
];

let milistaA: ListA[] = userListB;

//Obtengo un error de tipos porque el tipo de dato "id" no se puede convertir string a number
```

Alguna solucion a esto o definitivamente si se tiene que dejar iguales los tipos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un map y en el modificar el campo id.

```
let milistaA: ListA[] = userListB.map(element => {
    const newElem: ListaA = {
        id: Number(element.id),
        name: name
    };
    return newElem;
}
```

Comment: Justo lo aplique con el map, gracias!